# Set static field in generic class by type dynamically

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

I have a generic class and static field in it.

```
public class SomeGenericClass<T> : ISomeInterface<T> where T : SomeClass
{
    public static ISomeInterface<T> _someField;
}
```

And when I want to change value of this field, I have to change it for each type like this

```
var value = ...;
SomeGenericClass<Type1>._someField = value;
SomeGenericClass<Type2>._someField = value;
// ...
SomeGenericClass<Type3>._someField = value;
```

Is it possible to make it in loop, if I have array of types? I would like to see something like this

```
Type[] types = ... //Array of types
foreach(type in types){
    SomeGenericClass<type>._someField = value;
}
```

Or something like that.

Comment: What would you imagine `value`to be to fit all the types? And How would you know "all" the types?

Comment: Do you want to do it at compile time? You could use a T4 text template in that case, or at runtime, your would use runtime type information.

Comment: In my case, i have class "Entity", and about 8 ig his children. And i have generic class<T> where T:Entity. And i want to change this static field for each child of Entity class

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by reflection. First get the actual type:

```
var type = typeof(SomeGenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(theTypeArgument);
```

Now you can call `GetField` on that type in order to get the field:

```
var field = type.GetField("_someField");
```

Next set the value. Notice that the first parameter passed to `SetValue` is `null`, because the field is `static`:

```
field.SetValue(null, value);
```

Finally wrap this into a loop, e.g.:

```
foreach(var t in types)
{
    var type = typeof(SomeGenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(t);
    var field = type.GetField("_someField");
    field.SetValue(null, value);
}
```

Of course you should also add some checks to avoid `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I understood. But in my case type does not contain "_someField", it's in SomeGenericClass<type>

Comment: `var field = type.GetField("_someField");
field = null`

Comment: `type` already references `SomeGenericClass<MyType>`. Did you debug this and got `field == null`?

Comment: Yeah, when i make `field.SetValue(null,value);` got an exception, field is null

Comment: Used GetProperty instead of GetField and it worked, but now i have an exception
`System.ArgumentException: it is not possible to cast object of type "System.RuntimeType" toType "WpfApp.DataProvider.Repository.IDocumentRepository`1[WpfApp.Domain.Storage]".
   в System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   в System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)`

Comment: From the code you´ve posted `someField` was a **field**. So obviously the code above isn´t your *actual* code, where it seems to be a **property**. Anyway as of the other error it´s hard to get how that relates to the code you´ve posted above. This however seems to be a new problem unrelated o the original question.